# Tortoise SVN icon wrong under windows explorer

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

When something modified in a folder or in a file, svn should overlay a icon like:
[image: correct icon]

but I got a strange icon overlay instead:
[image: wrong icon]
at this time the windows explorer view is "details"

and I changed the explorer view to "middle symbol", the icon is correct again:
[image: correct icon]

where is the problem, how can I fix it?

Comment: URLs to screenshots missing

Comment: I have not enough stack overflow reputation jet to insert a screenshot...

Comment: now I can insert the screenshot

Answer (score 2):

Icon overlays in TortoiseSVN are a bit buggy (It's true in all TortoiseXXX clients). Window overlays are identified by an ID that's universal across the entire system and there's [a limited number of them too](http://www.sitepoint.com/missing-tortoisesvn-file-status-overlay-icons/). If another program is using overlays (maybe another Tortoise like client like TortoiseGIT or TortoiseHG, or maybe a chat client), it can mess up Tortoise's ability to use its overlays.

There is a way in TortoiseSVN to [rebuild the Icon cache](https://superuser.com/a/153623). Try that and see if that clears up the issue.